# Query Not working correctly in php using mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

```
 **DELETE.php**

<?php
include("db.php");
$id = $_GET['id'];
$check=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM details WHERE id='$id'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check))
{
   $sub=$row['sub'];
   $quan=$row['quan'];
}
$check1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM instock WHERE s_brand=$sub");
while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($check1))
{
    $qty1=$row1['qty'];
}
$check2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM outstock WHERE s_brand=$sub");
while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($check2))
{
    $qty2=$row2['qty'];
}
$test2=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE instock SET qty =$qty1+$quan WHERE 
s_brand='$sub'");
$test3=mysqli_query($conn,"UPDATE  outstock SET qty =$quan-$qty2 WHERE 
s_brand='$sub'");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "DELETE FROM details WHERE id=$id");
header("Location:add_sale.php");
?>
```

This is my delete.php file
 delete query works correctly.But two update queries are working wrongly.It's just set qty from $quan.
      I need immediately
      Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why is always while statement?

Comment: to retrieve data from other tables

Comment: I already tried it @bharatparmar

Comment: Do it with 1 query and parameterize your query.

Comment: try executing arithmatic operation on variable before assigning it directly to qty in update

Comment: Your `while` loops are repeatedly overwriting `$qty1` an `$qty2`. So you'll only get the value from the last row returned by the query.

Comment: You should learn to use prepared queries instead of substituting variables.

Comment: And you should check for errors from the queries, and print the error message if it fails.

Comment: You don't need separate `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries, you can do it all in a single query with `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second and third SELECT statements, I think you might need to add single quotes around $sub, so they would be:

```
$check1=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM instock WHERE s_brand='$sub'");
```

and

```
$check2=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM outstock WHERE s_brand='$sub'");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do all the updates in a single query, without any `SELECT`, by joining the queries.

```
$update_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "
    UPDATE details AS d
    JOIN outstock AS o ON o.brand = d.sub
    JOIN instock AS i ON i.brand = d.sub
    SET o.qty = o.qty - d.quan,
        i.qty = i.qty + d.quan
    WHERE d.id = ?") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($update_stmt, "i", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($update_stmt);
$delete_stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "DELETE FROM details WHERE id = ?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($delete_stmt, "i", $id);
mysqli_stmt_execute($delete_stmt);
```